# Simplify input code for nested dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

1. Hi, below is what I have currently, and it works well in this way.

   ```
   dict1 = {"INTC" : {"index":2,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"},
            "TSLA" : {"index":1,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"}, 
            "AMZN" : {"index":3,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"}}
   ```
2. But I want to have something like this

   ```
    INTC = {"index":2,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"}

    TSLA = {"index":1,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"}

    AMZN = {"index":3,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"}

    dict1 = dict(INTC, TSLA, AMZN)
   ```
3. Obviously, just having each symbol as a variable and copy-paste doesn't work. Do you have a better idea? My expected outcome is to freely write down symbols like "INTC" only instead of copy-paste the entire line of code: " INTC = {"index":2,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"}"

   I will have 100 different types of symbols like above and having each of long line of code will complicate things.
4. expected outcome example:

input(sudo-code):

```
dict1 = dict(INTC, TSLA)
```

output(not printed):

```
dict1 = {"INTC" : {"index":2,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"},
     "TSLA" : {"index":1,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type": "STK"}}
```

Comment: Your example is not valid Python, you can't pass 3 dictionaries to the `dict` constructor. What is your expected output?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you explain

Answer (score 0):

Unsure why you want to do this, it's hard to get the variable name directly. But you can do it by the inspect module like this:

```
import inspect

def dict_merge_var_name(dict_merged, var_unjoined):
    callers_local_vars = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items()
    for var_name, var_val in callers_local_vars:
        if var_val and var_val is var_unjoined and var_name != 'i':
            if not dict_merged.get(var_name):
                dict_merged[var_name] = var_val
            else:
                print("{0} already exists!".format(var_name))

INTC = {"index":2,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"}
TSLA = {"index":1,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"}
AMZN = {"index":3,"currency":"USD","exchange":"ISLAND", "sec_type":"STK"}
dict1 = {}

for i in [INTC, TSLA, AMZN]:
    print(i)
    dict_merge_var_name(dict1, i)

print(dict1)
```

Output will like this:

```
{'index': 2, 'currency': 'USD', 'exchange': 'ISLAND', 'sec_type': 'STK'}
{'index': 1, 'currency': 'USD', 'exchange': 'ISLAND', 'sec_type': 'STK'}
{'index': 3, 'currency': 'USD', 'exchange': 'ISLAND', 'sec_type': 'STK'}
{'INTC': {'index': 2, 'currency': 'USD', 'exchange': 'ISLAND', 'sec_type': 'STK'}, 'TSLA': {'index': 1, 'currency': 'USD', 'exchange': 'ISLAND', 'sec_type': 'STK'}, 'AMZN': {'index': 3, 'currency': 'USD', 'exchange': 'ISLAND', 'sec_type': 'STK'}}
```